# Refer to online js file in external js

Tags: javascript

I know that from the main HTML file, I can refer to my own external JS file with `<script src="/path/to/js.js">`. However, I'm using google maps in that external file, which I would normally load with `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>`, without an external file. Does it matter whether the `script src` tag is in the main or external file? How can I insert a reference to google's JS file into my external JS file?

Comment: If the script tag isn't in the main file, how would it know where to find the external file?

Comment: I would have a script tag in the main file pointing to my own 'external JS' file that I wrote. I want my external JS file to know where Google Maps' JS file is.

Answer (score 0):

To load an external javascript file with javascript, you could do something like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'URL_TO_EXTERNAL_JS';
script.async = true;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

This snippet creates a new script tag, sets the `src` and `async` attributes and appends it to the documents head.